# Filtering of values within a column based on the dates in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quantile, percentile

Hi all I have a pandas dataframe with columns Date and Values.
What I am trying to do is to keep values within the 25% and 75% quantile based on the different dates for the table below. Is there a way to do this?

| Date | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-1-23 | 455.0 |
| 2020-1-25 | 428.0 |
| 2020-1-25 | 379.0 |
| 2020-1-25 | 386.0 |
| 2020-1-26 | 385.0 |
| 2020-1-26 | 476.0 |
| 2020-1-26 | 427.0 |
| 2020-1-26 | 399.0 |
| 2020-1-26 | 374.0 |
| 2020-1-26 | 419.0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda functions and pass to [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
g = df.groupby('Date')['Values']
s1 = g.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.25))
s2 = g.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))

df = df[df['Values'].between(s1, s2)]
print (df)
        Date  Values
0  2020-1-23   455.0
3  2020-1-25   386.0
7  2020-1-26   399.0
9  2020-1-26   419.0
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.join(df.groupby('Date')['Values'].quantile([0.25,0.75]).unstack(), on='Date')

df = df[df['Values'].between(df1[0.25], df1[0.75])]
print (df)
        Date  Values
0  2020-1-23   455.0
3  2020-1-25   386.0
7  2020-1-26   399.0
9  2020-1-26   419.0
```